# Translating Shortcut keys in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I am making a notepad like program in Ubuntu. I have this idea that If my notepad program is open but currently not in focus that is may be I opened a folder or something and my program is behind that window, If I want to paste some data to my notepad, and I press CTRL+P , that data gets pasted to the notepad file even when the notepad is behind that window.

The problem is I don't know how to detect which keys are pressed when my notepad is behind a window. How can I do it?I heard there is a System call for this purpose. I am programming in C++

Regards

Answer (score 0):

One (not uncommon) solution is to make your program act a network server *and* client. This way you can call your program with special arguments that are interpreted as commands to send to the currently running program. Then you can make a standard Ubuntu Unity hotkey that calls your program with an argument that means "connect to running program and send the command 'paste'".

Of course, you can utilise dbus or other RPC frameworks to do this rather than incorporate this into a command-line only version of your program.

Comment: By chance do you have updates to this answer from 2012? I have the same issue create custom shortcut key in Ubuntu Unity and have it send signal to non-focused python toplevel window to click button 2.